# 'No connection string named 'IICMDATAEntities' could be found in the application config file.' EF6 - Revit Add-in

Tags: mvvm, add-in, revit-api

am build file .dll Revit Add-in has Entity Framework 6 and my errors  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9m8Mo.png) Help me

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to let your command know where your `app.config` is. For some reason, we have this issue with RevitAPI.
Ok, but... How we do that?
To begin with, you need to add a reference to `System.Configuration.dll`.
It's easily found if you right click *"References"* in your solution explorer, and then under *"Assemblies"* tab, search for configuration:

[image]

Then, you need to create a `Configuration`object, giving the exact location of your addin dll.
The following piece of code does exact that:

```
 Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration
                (System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
 var connString = config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["DevelopmentConnection"].ConnectionString;
```

With the connection string value in hand, you can simply pass it to the constructor of your `DbContext` inside your `Execute` method:

```
    [Autodesk.Revit.Attributes.Transaction(Autodesk.Revit.Attributes.TransactionMode.Manual)]
    [Autodesk.Revit.Attributes.Regeneration(Autodesk.Revit.Attributes.RegenerationOption.Manual)]
    public class MyRevitAPICommand : IExternalCommand
    {
        public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, ElementSet elements)
        {
            MyContext myContext = new MyContext(connString);
            //if using mvvm, can pass this context around to achieve what you desire.
        }
    }
```

Done!